# batch "convert" into jpg with nice alpha flatten

Tags: command-line, convert, imagemagick, batch, mogrify

I would like to batch resize and convert to jpg a few png files. But some pixels are transparent, and some are half transparent; I would like the transparent ones to be white, and the half-transparent ones to be white half mixed with color.

I have two half solutions:

```
convert file.png -resize 1200x1200  -background white -flatten  file.jpg
```

which works well, but only for one file; so is there an easy way to batch the "convert" command? I want my files to keep their names, which are not numbered (img001.png, img002.png, etc.) but descriptive (room.png, horse.png, etc.)... Or:

```
mogrify -resize 1200x1200 -format jpg -background "#FFFFFF" *.png
```

which batches well, but the half-transparent pixels are full color, which is pretty ugly when a line is supposed to fade into alpha; is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can mogrify not use the `-flatten` option, then?

Comment: oh, it works. I didn't know that's what it was for. Thanks!

Comment: `mogrify` and `convert` are both programs from the ImageMagick project. There may be some exceptions, but generally they have the same options.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`for` loop](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html):

```
for f in ./*.png; do convert "$f" -resize -background white -flatten "${f%.*}.jpg"; done
```

This will operate on every file with a name ending in `.png` in the current directory. Each go around on the loop, the matched filename is read into the variable `$f`; in order to massage this information into the output filename, the above command uses [parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

> `${var%Pattern}` -- Remove from `$var` the shortest part of `$Pattern` that matches the back end of `$var`.
>
> `${var%%Pattern}` -- Remove from `$var` the longest part of `$Pattern` that matches the back end of `$var`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, batch naming is tricky! I'll use the other answer, it's simpler, but this could help me later.